# Mount NTFS drive in Synology NAS via bay

Tags: nas, synology

I'm working in a situation where I specifically want to use one empty drive bay in my Synology NAS to mount a hard drive, copy the contents to the raid, and then remove the drive. However, the DiskStation OS (DSM) only gives options to initialize the disk. What would be a way to achieve this?

I have tried a solution posted on the Synology site from 2010, without success [(site)](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/23952)

Comment: Would it be an option to connect the drive via a USB enclosure or dock?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you probably can mount the drive from the terminal. I'm not sure if DSM will see it though.

Comment: @mashuptwice if you re-read the question, you'll see that the answer is no

Comment: @Shawn I've read that part and asked specifically because of that. As Romeo pointed out you could try to mount it via terminal if there are NTFS drivers availible for synology.

Answer (score 0):

Synology support for internal disks only `ext4` and `btrfs`. So as it is mentioned in commend connect this drive via USB and copy the information.